# Terraform Nested Loops 1.12

Tags: terraform, nested-loops, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to implement nested for loops using Terraform 1.12 in order to loop through Azure users, each of which can have one or more values attached. The variable used to represent this list is of type map(list(string)) and looks something like this:

```
VirtualMachine = {
  app = {
    Size = "Standard_B4ms"
    Disks = {
      OS = {
        Cache = "ReadWrite"
        Size  = 128
        Type  = "Premium_LRS"
      }
      Data = {
        Cache = "ReadWrite"
        Size  = 64
        Type  = "Premium_LRS" 
      }
    }
    Image = {
      Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
      Offer     = "WindowsServer"
      Sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition"
      Version   = "latest"
    }
  }
}
```

I am attempting construct that list and store it in a local variable like so, where

```
  vmDisks = {
    for key, value in flatten([
      for vmKey, vm in var.VirtualMachine : [
        for diskKey, disk in vm.Disks.Data : {
          VmId   = vmKey
          DiskId = diskKey
          Cache  = disk.Cache
          Type   = disk.Type
          Size   = disk.Size
          Lun    = 1 + index(keys(vm.Disks.Data), diskKey)
      }
    ]
    if contains(keys(vm.Disks), "Data")
    ]) : "${value.VmId}.${value.DiskId}" => value
  }
```

However, I am getting errors when attempting to access the values in that nested list.

Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on locals.tf line 48, in locals:
│   48:           Cache  = disk.Cache
│
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string)

can you help me here?

I have tried to pass diskKey[0] with the reference local.association-list[count.index][0] and fails at terraform plan stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your inner loop:
`for diskKey, disk in vm.Disks.Data`
The `disk` is not what you think, here is an example:

```
locals {
  vmDisks = {
    for key, value in flatten([
      for vmKey, vm in var.VirtualMachine : [
        for diskKey, disk in vm.Disks.Data : {
          VmId   = vmKey
          DiskId = diskKey
          disk  = disk
          Lun    = 1 + index(keys(vm.Disks.Data), diskKey)
        }
      ]
      if contains(keys(vm.Disks), "Data")
    ]) : "${value.VmId}.${value.DiskId}" => value
  }
}

output "test" {
    value = local.vmDisks
}

variable "VirtualMachine" {
  default = {
    app = {
      Size = "Standard_B4ms"
      Disks = {
        OS = {
          Cache = "ReadWrite"
          Size  = 128
          Type  = "Premium_LRS"
        }
        Data = {
          Cache = "ReadWrite"
          Size  = 64
          Type  = "Premium_LRS"
        }
      }
      Image = {
        Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
        Offer     = "WindowsServer"
        Sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition"
        Version   = "latest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the output of that is this:

```
  + test = {
      + app.Cache = {
          + DiskId = "Cache"
          + Lun    = 1
          + VmId   = "app"
          + disk   = "ReadWrite"
        }
      + app.Size  = {
          + DiskId = "Size"
          + Lun    = 2
          + VmId   = "app"
          + disk   = 64
        }
      + app.Type  = {
          + DiskId = "Type"
          + Lun    = 3
          + VmId   = "app"
          + disk   = "Premium_LRS"
        }
    }
```

As you can see the disk is just a value not an object

Comment: What if if the construct has to read entire block of virtual machine Disks [OS, Data]?

Comment: Disks = {
        OS = {
          Cache = "ReadWrite"
          Size  = 128
          Type  = "Premium_LRS"
        }
        Data = {
          Cache = "ReadWrite"
          Size  = 64
          Type  = "Premium_LRS"
        }}

Comment: @Mahs If you need to read the entire block just change the `in vm.Disks.Data`  ... I would recommend you to post a sample of what you like your `local.vmDisks` structure to look like and we can work on it

Comment: Sorry for being late here. I was looking for below tfvars which would read in below mentioned output; 

+ test = {
      + app.Disks.OS = {
          
        }
      + app.Disks.Data = {
         Data1 {}
         Data2 {}
        
        }
 }

Comment: tfvars: VirtualMachine = {
  app = {
    Size = "Standard_B2ms"

    Disks = {
      OS = {
        Cache = "ReadWrite"
        Size  = 128
        Type  = "Premium_LRS"
      }

      Data = {
        Data-1 = {
          Cache = "ReadWrite"
          Size   = 64
          Type   = "Premium_LRS"
        }
        Data-2 = {
          Cache = "ReadWrite"
          Size   = 64
          Type   = "Premium_LRS"
        }
      }
    }